# Carbon Bootstrap class not found when using YAJSW to start WSO2CEP as Windows service

Tags: windows-services, wso2, yajsw, wso2-cep

We have been using `YAJSW version beta-12.05` to install `WSO2CEP` as Windows service. It has worked once until we restarted the server and it has become failed to start up and reported error log as below.

```
WARNING|wrapper|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:06|YAJSW: yajsw-beta-12.04
WARNING|wrapper|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:06|OS   : Windows 7/6.1/amd64
WARNING|wrapper|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:06|JVM  : Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_74/C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\jre/64
WARNING|wrapper|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:07|working directory ?unresolved?\ not found
INFO|wrapper|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:08|started process with pid 3900
INFO|3900/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:09|[INFO] StandardFileSystemManager - Using "C:\Programs\WSO2CEP\yajsw-beta-12.05\?unresolved?\tmp\vfs_cache" as temporary files store.
INFO|3900/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:09|java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap
INFO|3900/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:09|    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
INFO|3900/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:09|    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
INFO|3900/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:09|    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
INFO|3900/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:09|    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
INFO|3900/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:09|    at org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperManagerImpl.init(WrapperManagerImpl.java:327)
INFO|3900/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:09|    at org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperManagerProxy.getWrapperManager(WrapperManagerProxy.java:53)
INFO|3900/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:09|    at org.rzo.yajsw.app.AbstractWrapperJVMMain$1.run(AbstractWrapperJVMMain.java:64)
INFO|3900/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:09|    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
INFO|3900/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:09|    at org.rzo.yajsw.app.AbstractWrapperJVMMain.preExecute(AbstractWrapperJVMMain.java:56)
INFO|3900/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:09|    at org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain.main(WrapperJVMMain.java:41)
INFO|3900/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:09|error finding main method in class: org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap : org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap
INFO|3900/0|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:09|no java main method found -> aborting
INFO|wrapper|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:09|executed script: scripts/trayMessage.gv 1
INFO|wrapper|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:10|restart process due to default exit code rule
INFO|wrapper|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:10|restart internal RUNNING
INFO|wrapper|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:10|stopping process with pid/timeout 3900 45000
INFO|wrapper|Service "WSO2 Carbon"|16-05-13 10:35:10|process exit code: 999
```

However, if we just start the WSO2CEP by its wso2server.bat in bin folder, it is works. And I have also tried to copy whole YAJSW folder to another server and installed service, it is works too.

It seesms that the WSO2CEP and YAJSW both works fine, but will failed to start as service on the particularly server.

The server specific is as below:

```
OS   : Windows 7/6.1/amd64
JVM  : Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_74/C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\jre/64
```

Comment: Can you please make sure that you have followed following guide to configure jajsw conf. Seems your working directory is not properly set.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon443/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service

Comment: Hi @Tishan, thanks for the reply. Yes, I have figured it out, that is because I forget to set CARBON_HOME on that server. After adding set CARBON_HOME=path_to_the_folder before the service register command in the batch, it works. Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you have followed following guide to configure jajsw conf. Seems your working directory is not properly set. docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon443/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service